# In what way is Jesus different from other sons of God according to Biblical Unitarians?

Tags: life-of-jesus, christology, biblical-unitarian

There are other questions regarding this topic from different perspectives.

**What is different about Jesus compared to other 'sons of God' from a Biblical Unitarian perspective?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In what way Jesus the "Son of God" is different from the other "son/sons of God" in the Bible?**

1. Jesus was a man without sin. Yes there was another man, Adam, but none remained without sin. Adam was a *type* of Jesus who was to come, "in these last days" Heb 1 tells us. Adam was never meant to carry the plan of salvation on his shoulders, but his sinless beginning is the only one who may be aligned with Jesus.
2. Jesus could die. The angels cannot (as far as we know). Just as Adam could die, by bleeding to death etc, Jesus was exactly the same - made of flesh and blood just like all men since Adam. Gen 6:2, Job 1:6 angels as sons of God.

   > Therefore, in all things he had to be made like his brothers Heb 2:17

   > be made like his brothers **in every respect** ESV

   Being an angel, as some purport, is not *like us*. (For that matter, being also God is not made like us either)

   While there are many references to 'sons of God', Jesus is the unique son who was planned from before the world began to be the one as Paul says, 'the *reason* for God creating all things'.

   > in him (Jesus) were created all things in the heavens and upon the earth, the visible and the invisible, whether thrones or lordships or rulers or authorities; all things have been created through him and unto him. Col 1:16

   The Gospels proclaim quite clearly *how* Jesus came to be - through Mary, God miraculously enabled her to conceive and bear the son in the lineage of Abraham and David.
3. No other 'son of God' has this promised lineage. Promised to Abraham and David regarding a people and a throne to last forever.
4. No other 'son of God' can claim to be the Messiah.

   > Therefore having been exalted at the right hand of God, and having received the promise of the holy spirit from the Father, he has poured out this which you are both seeing and hearing.... 36Therefore let all the house of Israel know assuredly that **God has made him both Lord and Christ**—this Jesus whom you crucified.” Acts 2:33-
5. No other 'son of God' has *transitioned* from physical to spiritual. Jesus is the firstborn from the dead, the first of many brothers who was mortal, but is now immortal with a *spirit life* he didn't have before and sits by the side of God. Rom 8:29, 1Pet 3:18

(Compiled from https://www.biblicalunitarian.com/articles/jesus-is-the-son-of-god-not-god-the-son) and other related pages.

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted: this is a very clear explanation of Unitarian teaching. Only thing that could be improved is if a reference could be added to a textual article rather than only a video.

Comment: Yes, well, you get used to it after a while. If it's not trinitarian, it gets a DV automatically.